# React/Nginx - Unable to access static files

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-config

I've built my React project and would like to deploy this with Nginx.

**React Build Directory**

[image: React Build Directory]

**Nginx Configuration**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.css {
        add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    }
    location ~ \.js {
        add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
    }
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

The page is hosted in a subdirectory. E.g. `<url>/example`. It appears that the index file is loaded successfully however it is unable to access the `main` js, css and manifest files.

[image]

How can I allow the files within the `static` folder to be accessed?

**Update**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;

    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        include mime.types;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

The contents of the `build` directory are placed in `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

Assets are referred in the `index.html` as `/example/static/js/main.99d6e906.js` which works correctly when using the build directory locally.

I've searched for a `base href` in the `index.html` but there isn't one. It looks like `React` has appended the `/example` subdirectory name as I specified the `homepage` field in the `package.json` to be `/example`.

Comment: You should move your `root` declaration one level up, your other locations are using default `<prefix>/html` one right now. You'd better include correct `mime.types` at some upper level and remove those regex locations at all.

Comment: I've tried using `include mime.types` and it is now finding the files, however the files contain `html` instead of `js` or `css`. This causes an `Unexpected Token` error.

Comment: Your `index.html` most likely served via all the assetst links. Too many unknown details to answer your question. Where do you place your `build` folder? How is your nginx config looking right now? How your assets referred inside your `index.html`? What is the `<BASE HREF="..."/>` value in your `index.html`, if any?

Comment: If you specify your `homepage` as `/example`, that means you want your app to be accessible as `http://localhost/example/` rather than `http://localhost/`? That will require additional changes to the nginx configuration (as well as to the React router).